# Hibernate vs Spring compatibility

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, dependency-injection

Hi I have next maven dependencies [image: Dependecies]

When I deployed next error was taken:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

And I guess this is a version problems, but I don't know what versions of hibernate should be used.

Comment: You are mixing versions of spring 4.0.1 and 4.1.7. Make the `spring-orm` jar match the other spring versions.

Comment: Try searching for class in  org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 package.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/package-summary.html here it stats that the package is different so you might have to change your versions as M.Deinum mentioned :)